# How to handle interruptions during downloading large file in android?

Tags: android

I have to download one large compressed file (contains multiple files) from an FTP server. During downloading, if it is interrupted/paused by the user or network, the broken downloaded file should be saved. Later, user can resume download the same file from where it is broken.

Comment: In the title i think. :). Firefox save the file while downloading. IDM save each part then marge when download is completed.

Comment: I need the same function in android.

Answer (score 3):

You can use DownloadManager class.

Download manager is a system service that handles long-running HTTP downloads.

Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html

Above class available since API level 9.

Comment: I want to continue the downloading even if it is closed.

Comment: Do you mean download should continue even if the application is closed? or something else

Comment: ya.. If the application is closed the downloaded file should be saved, and later resume download the same file from where it is broken.

Comment: If you want to stop the download and start it later, then i'm sorry i did't tried it before, so dont have any idea. please post it as a question.

Answer (score 0):

One can set the range of bytes to download using the Range HTTP header. All you have to do is remember how many bytes you previously downloaded. Using the classes from apache, it would look like this :

```
DefaultHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(youSourceUri);

// That's the important part. Count represents the number of bytes already downloaded.
// We leave the range open, so it will download 'till the end of the file.
httpGet.addHeader(new BasicHeader("Range", "bytes=" + count + "-"));

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();

// Then read from the input stream
```

Remember to add the appropriate try/catch/finally clauses to handle the streams safely and be sure to close them. They were omitted here for readability.